# How can i get last week, current week and last month record from mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, strtotime

i am storing date in strtotime format in codeigniter. and week start from sunday.

```
$this->db->where($this->weight . '.create_date <=', 'curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY');
$this->db->where($this->weight . '.create_date >', 'curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY');
```

Comment: for current week

create_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK

for last week

create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK

for last month

create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For taking last week:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

For taking current week:

```
WHERE  YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

For taking last month:

```
year(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))) = year(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
and month(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))) = month(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: what is u.create?

Comment: @JuliverGalleto its your table date column