# How to get data of previous week in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to get data inserted in previous week in Laravel 5.1. Currently I am using following query:

```
$AgoDate=\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeek()->format('Y-m-d');  // returns 2016-02-03
$NowDate=\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');  // returns 2016-02-10
$query->whereBetween('created_on', array($AgoDate,$NowDate));
```

This returns last 7 days data, but I need last week's data, which means it should return data from 31st Jan to 6th Feb, i.e. the previous week.

Note: in my case Week starts from Sunday and ends on Saturday.

Comment: How about raw mysql query?

Comment: ok you can post your answer in raw mysql, i will convert it in laravel, please tell me if you have any

Comment: So check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936174/how-can-i-get-last-week-current-week-and-last-month-record-from-mysql/28936788#28936788`, let me know if its not the one that you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: adjusting to OP's question

For ago date use

```
$currentDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$agoDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek)->subWeek();// gives 2016-01-31
```

Similarly you can get your nowDate

```
$currentDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$nowDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek + 1); // gives 2016-02-06
```

to adjust the weekstart(sunday/monday) I think you can add/subtract some days to dayOfWeek e.g `$currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek + 1 /* or -1 */);`

EDIT : as mentioned in the comments you can also use `startOfWeek()` method instead of `subDays()` if it works directly for you.

Comment: or `$agoDate = $currentDate->startOfWeek()->subWeek();`

Comment: Thanks @RalphJohnGalindo, had missed it :)

Comment: @RalphJohnGalindo, &codeHeart But it gives monday, i need to start week from sunday

Comment: @Insomania as mentioned in the answer, you can add some number to change to week start  e.g  in your case if you need to get $nowDate to be 2016-02-06, then do something like $nowDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek + 1);

Comment: @codeHeart Thanks so much, it really works like a charm :)